# How do I ask/hint to Google not to index something on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, noscript

I have a web site that mostly displays images that contain text. It is heavy with JavaScript. In a noscript tag we have the usual "You must have JavaScript enabled" message followed by the text extracted from the image. My problem is that Google indexes the "You must have JavaScript enabled" message. So when you get a hit on my site, this is in the description. I'd rather not have Google index this at all, but if I can at least get it out of the description that'd be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also see SO question [Display a “No Javascript” div, but not to google / facebook share servic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388648/display-a-no-javascript-div-but-not-to-google-facebook-share-service), which I believe better answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

Just provide your own description in `<head>`.

```
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum.">
```

This will appear in the site description in Google results. It can contain about 150 words.

#### See also:

- [Changing your site's title and description in Google results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35264)