# How to display an image fullscreen on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the script from previous stack overflow question on how to pick an image from an array at random.

[Script to display an image selected at random from an array on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809188/script-to-display-an-image-selected-at-random-from-an-array-on-page-load)

I want to take his idea a bit further, and display this image fullscreen on page load. I am working on a website, and had the idea to use an image as a greeting page. Where, when the page loads, you are greeted with a fullscreen HD image. When clicked, this image would disappear and show the full site. I wasn't exactly sure how to accomplish this though. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm not looking for direct implementation. Just general thoughts or jsFiddles on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Atleast post the code you've tried to accomplish your idea.

Comment: That would include multiple style sheets and and script files. There is simply too much to just post.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CSS` like,

**First** option,

```
img {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**Second** option,

```
img {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

To understand the above options read [Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

I recommend you to use a complete full page background image slider for your problem. If it is available then use it without wasting your time.

I found a full page slider on http://www.freshdesignweb.com/fullscreen-jquery-slider.html in which the first one [background slider](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/BackgroundSlideshow/) is best suitable to you.

Also you can go to https://www.google.co.in/?q=full+background+image+slider to get more image sliders

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me. I actually have read the link before, and understand the CSS fairly well. Its the Jquery that I need help with. Its scripting the image to display on page load and then to disappear when clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure if thats exactly what I'm looking for, but feel free to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

For showing the image on the page load you can use `$( document ).ready()` function. on `click()` of the image you could show the website.

Comment: Thats what I've been trying, but from there I'm stuck. Do I try .addClass or .attr? These choices are what's giving me trouble.

Comment: for what. if you have css class then do the `addClass()`. can show the bit of code only used for this.

Comment: Here is a basic jsFiddle where two things arnt working: 1: the orange page wrapper div isn't floating above everything 2: the .click isn't working as intended. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mc1Lep5c/

Comment: when using `addClass()` don't specify `. (dot)` in front of class. use only `addClass('page-image')`

Comment: use  `$(this).css("background-color", "green");` instead of `addClass('page-image')`