# noscript google snapshot, the safe way

Tags: php, javascript, seo, noscript

I have a page that is so javascript intensive I can't even begin to write the equivalent PHP for it. That being the case, the page has a `<noscript>` tag that says the page is unviewable to non-js users.

Anyway it is possible for me to serve up a snapshot version of the page so that google can see what the page contains and so that people can find my pages by searching for phrases.

So is there a way for me to have my cake and eat it too? Meaning can I have a blank page for non-js users but if a google bot comes along serve it a skeleton page?

How would I even go about doing this? Also will doing something like this hurt my rankings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be worth noting that Googlebot is known to execute a significant amount of Javascript now. So long as the page which loads has all the necessary content on it, you may be fine (for Google at least -- other search engines, perhaps less so).

Failing that: You don't necessarily need to have all the *exact* same content in the noscript version of the page, just an attempt to convey the same sort of information. I don't know what your site involves, but if you can just dump a basic text representation of the page's content, that might be sufficient.

Comment: I'd recommend also making sure navigation is also available in the noscript version..

Answer (score 2):

You could serve something different to user agents with `Googlebot` in them, but this is very risky, as Google can detect it as an attempt to scam their robot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know: [Google policy on serving different content based on user info.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355)

> Cloaking refers to the practice of presenting different content or
>   URLs to users and search engines. Serving up different results based
>   on user-agent may cause your site to be perceived as deceptive and
>   removed from the Google index.
>
> Some examples of cloaking include:
>
> ```
> Serving a page of HTML text to search engines, while showing a page of images or Flash to users.
> Serving different content to search engines than to users.
> ```
>
> If your site contains elements that aren't crawlable by search engines
>   (such as rich media files other than Flash, JavaScript, or images),
>   you shouldn't provide cloaked content to search engines. Rather, you
>   should consider visitors to your site who are unable to view these
>   elements as well. For instance:
>
> ```
> Provide alt text that describes images for visitors with screen readers or images turned off in their browsers.
> Provide the textual contents of JavaScript in a noscript tag.
> ```
>
> Ensure that you provide the same content in both elements (for
>   instance, provide the same text in the JavaScript as in the noscript
>   tag). Including substantially different content in the alternate
>   element may cause Google to take action on the site. Sneaky JavaScript
>   redirects
>
> When Googlebot indexes a page containing JavaScript, it will index
>   that page but it may not follow or index any links hidden in the
>   JavaScript itself. Use of JavaScript is an entirely legitimate web
>   practice. However, use of JavaScript with the intent to deceive search
>   engines is not. For instance, placing different text in JavaScript
>   than in a noscript tag violates our Webmaster Guidelines because it
>   displays different content for users (who see the JavaScript-based
>   text) than for search engines (which see the noscript-based text).
>   Along those lines, it violates the Webmaster Guidelines to embed a
>   link in JavaScript that redirects the user to a different page with
>   the intent to show the user a different page than the search engine
>   sees. When a redirect link is embedded in JavaScript, the search
>   engine indexes the original page rather than following the link,
>   whereas users are taken to the redirect target. Like cloaking, this
>   practice is deceptive because it displays different content to users
>   and to Googlebot, and can take a visitor somewhere other than where
>   they intended to go.
>
> Note that placement of links within JavaScript is alone not deceptive.
>   When examining JavaScript on your site to ensure your site adheres to
>   our guidelines, consider the intent.
>
> Keep in mind that since search engines generally can't access the
>   contents of JavaScript, legitimate links within JavaScript will likely
>   be inaccessible to them (as well as to visitors without
>   Javascript-enabled browsers). You might instead keep links outside of
>   JavaScript or replicate them in a noscript tag. Doorway pages
>
> Doorway pages are typically large sets of poor-quality pages where
>   each page is optimized for a specific keyword or phrase. In many
>   cases, doorway pages are written to rank for a particular phrase and
>   then funnel users to a single destination.
>
> Whether deployed across many domains or established within one domain,
>   doorway pages tend to frustrate users, and are in violation of our
>   Webmaster Guidelines.
>
> Google's aim is to give our users the most valuable and relevant
>   search results. Therefore, we frown on practices that are designed to
>   manipulate search engines and deceive users by directing them to sites
>   other than the ones they selected, and that provide content solely for
>   the benefit of search engines. Google may take action on doorway sites
>   and other sites making use of these deceptive practice, including
>   removing these sites from the Google index.
>
> If your site has been removed from our search results, review our
>   Webmaster Guidelines for more information. Once you've made your
>   changes and are confident that your site no longer violates our
>   guidelines, submit your site for reconsideration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar issue with a website, and there is a way to serve up a HTML snapshot of the page. You can find it here on Google Developers:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started
This page was last updated February 2012.

There's also the option to add a noscript tag in front of the content, which is a faster solution but which does have the possibility of being seen by Google as an attempt to skew ranking. From the research that I have done, people were posting about this type of tag as a solution around 2008-2010.

Although Googlebot can execute some Javascript, and this is something that Google is working on improving, it doesn't say that it is executing all Javascript on the site. From what I have found online, Google is only executing Javascript on the most heavily traversed pages of a site. I'd still recommend serving up the HTML snapshot but I don't like it.

It's possible to check the Apache log to see if Google is executing Javascript on your page.

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/05/googles-bots-learn-to-read-interactive-web-pages-more-like-humans/