# Web-app with AngularJS: Show error-page in case JavaScript deactivated in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in case that the user has deactivated JavaScript in his browser, i would like to show an error-message
that my AngularJS-WeppApp can not be shown.

My first idea for doing this is to show this error-message by default and to replace it with my Angular-
startpage when JavaScript is activated in browser.

My questions: is there a better idea and/or is there a standard-way to handle the problem with deactivated
JavaScript and AngularJS-Apps.

Comment: The `<noscript>` element is for this. See [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Noscript Tag, JavaScript Disabled Warning and Google Penalty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993387/noscript-tag-javascript-disabled-warning-and-google-penalty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<noscript></noscript>` tag will be executed if the javascript is disabled in the browser.

the 
`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.domain.com/javascriptdisable.html">`
tag is executed to redirect the page from the client side when the content is removed from the page to redirect the client to the updated page.

so play smart

in the head section of your html tag

```
<head>
  <noscript>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.domain.com/javascriptdisable.html">
  </noscript>
</head>
```